# Trying to Trigger Javascript onBlur event for form validation getting null error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write form validation that alerts that user if they move to a input text field without inputting any value, everytime I test it firebug I get the error:

> TypeError: firstName is null
>
> firstName.onblur = ValidateForm;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("firstname").onblur = ValidateForm; 

    function ValidateForm() {
        var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname");
        if(firstName.value == 0) {
                alert("You need to enter a value into the first name field bro");
                firstName.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works when I use `window.onload = ValidateForm;` but I wanted to try it using this event handler

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I know I can use                                                   
First Name: <input type="text" size="30" name="firstname" onblur="ValidateForm()" id="firstname" />

But I wanted to use an easier way without having to add the event to each input element

Comment: Is your script placed after your DOM elements? (i.e., at the end of the body element?). I think you're trying to attach an event handler to an object that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: You were totally right, I put the script below the form and it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript code looks fine. 
Make sure you have the javascript after .... If you declare your event handler before relevant HTML fragment, it might work in firefox but not chrome. And it also explains that why window.load works in this case.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a bunch gotta write that down.

Comment: You were totally right, I put the script below the form and it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch.